# Cannot get NSManagedObject.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent to work

Tags: ios, core-data

I've rewritten our iOS app to use the new iOS 10 features in Core Data. In particular I've switched the Core Data stack creation to to the new NSPersistentStore setup.

We already had a main queue context and a background context, so we're using those straight from the NSPersistentStore object. I've also changed from using notifications to merge changes across contexts to setting the new automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent in both the viewContext and the backgroundContext.

Unfortunately, I'm now getting a number of weird crashes in our NSFetchedResultsController which updates a UICollectionViewController and view.

So I set the "-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1" launch argument to make sure things were happening on the correct queues and I get an immediate exception when the background thread tries to save the background object context, even though the stack trace shows the exception happening on the "correct" background queue:

```
#0  0x00000001948b89bc in +[NSManagedObjectContext __Multithreading_Violation_AllThatIsLeftToUsIsHonor__] ()
#1  0x0000000194853724 in -[_PFBatchFaultingArray managedObjectIDAtIndex:] ()
#2  0x0000000194853600 in -[_PFMutableProxyArray newArrayFromObjectIDs] ()
#3  0x0000000194853548 in -[_PFMutableProxyArray arrayFromObjectIDs] ()
#4  0x0000000194852638 in -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _managedObjectContextDidSave:] ()
#5  0x00000001924e622c in __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ ()
#6  0x00000001924e5930 in _CFXRegistrationPost ()
#7  0x00000001924e56ac in ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke ()
#8  0x0000000192554b9c in -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] ()
#9  0x0000000192427bf4 in _CFXNotificationPost ()
#10 0x0000000192f2e6bc in -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] ()
#11 0x00000001948c5b48 in -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalNotificationHandling) _postContextDidSaveNotificationWithUserInfo:] ()
#12 0x0000000194850350 in -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _didSaveChanges] ()
#13 0x000000019483ca0c in -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] ()
```

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong? Here's some of the relevant code:

```
var initializationError: NSError?

// The persistent container (local database) for the application.
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: self.storeName)
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            self.initializationError = error // This will be displayed by the AppDelegate
        }
    })
    return container
}()

// The managed object context for the main thread of the application.
lazy var mainObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {

    // Get the main thread context.
    let context = self.persistentContainer.viewContext
    context.mergePolicy = NSOverwriteMergePolicy // In-memory properties overwrite datastore properties
    context.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true // Merge all changes.

    return context
}()

// Return a managed object for background threads to create and modify objects without affecting the main thread until necessary.
lazy var backgroundObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {

    // Get a background thread context.
    let context = self.persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
    context.mergePolicy = NSOverwriteMergePolicy // In-memory properties overwrite datastore properties
    context.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true // Merge all changes.

    return context

}()

// Synchronously save any pending object changes in a managed object context to the database persistent store.
class func saveAnyChangesSync(_ context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> NSError? {

    var error: NSError?

    // If the context has changes, save them.
    if context.hasChanges {

        do {
            try context.save()

        } catch let saveError as NSError {
            error = saveError
            NSLog("CoreData error saving context \(saveError)")
        }
    }
    return error
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it is implemented internally using child contexts? In WWDC, we were told by CD developers that child/parent mode is not recommended anymore with the new internal changes.

Comment: Are you using the background and view contexts correctly otherwise in your app?

Answer (score 2):

If you are managing core data in Swift and not seeing changes propagated between your background saves and primary context, you (like me) might be missing the autoreleasepool part (pfffbt! objective-c). I saw a bunch of errors before making this change, although mine were all about NSSet being mutated.

You might also want to look at merge policy - I don't think both contexts should have the same policy. Primary should yield to file store and background shoudl stick to current object changes.

Abbreviated example:

```
// When initializing:
persistentContainer.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
 persistentContainer.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy.mergeByPropertyStoreTrump
// And when saving:
persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask { moc in
    moc.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    moc.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy.mergeByPropertyObjectTrump
    autoreleasepool {
        // ... do some nsmanagedobject loading/changing
    }
    do {
        try moc.save()
    } catch {}
}
```

Comment: Good note about different `.mergePolicy` for different contexts, thanks! Meanwhile, I think `moc.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true` is redundant for a temporary background context because you create it for only one specific task.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess `saveAnyChangesSync` is being called from the main thread with the background context, in which case you would need to use context's perform method.

```
/* asynchronously performs the block on the context's queue.  Encapsulates an autorelease pool and a call to processPendingChanges */
- (void)performBlock:(void (^)(void))block API_AVAILABLE(macosx(10.7),ios(5.0));

/* synchronously performs the block on the context's queue.  May safely be called reentrantly.  */
- (void)performBlockAndWait:(void (NS_NOESCAPE ^)(void))block API_AVAILABLE(macosx(10.7),ios(5.0));
```